# "message": "Optional int parameter 'year' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, object

This is my BookController class, PUT method:

```
@PutMapping(path = "{bookId}")
public void updateBook(
        @PathVariable("bookId") Long bookId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String author,
        @RequestParam(required = false) int year,
        @RequestParam(required = false) double price) {
    bookService.updateBook(bookId, title, author, year, price);
}
```

In generated-requests.http when I use PUT method

```
###
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/book/2?title="Red dragon 2"
Content-Type: application/json
```

I get following error:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/book/2?title=%22Red+dragon+2%22

HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 02 Sep 2021 14:53:56 GMT
Connection: close


{
"timestamp": "2021-09-02T14:53:56.417+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Optional int parameter 'year' is present but cannot be translated into a null value
due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the 
corresponding primitive type.",
"path": "/api/v1/book/2"
}

Response code: 500; Time: 241ms; Content length: 331 bytes
```

Cannot understand why this error happened at all and how do I declare it as object wrapper?
Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Just stick to the OOP alternative:

```
@PutMapping(path = "{bookId}")
public void updateBook(
        @PathVariable("bookId") Long bookId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String title,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String author,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer year,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Double price) {
    bookService.updateBook(bookId, title, author, year, price);
}
```

Integer is the Object Oriented Programming equivalent of an int. It is not a primitive type, but an object and you can use it in this case, because you are expecting the value to be null.